# ASP.NET Core 2.1 dynamic display properties based on configuration from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

We have a non-trivial requirement that the same view model (JournalVoucher) can have many "Types" (which are user configured) and for each "Type" the properties in JournalVoucher would have different display names and validation rules that all come from user-defined configurations in the DB. For example in a sales voucher the Agent property would have the display name "Customer", and in a purchase voucher the display name would be "Supplier" and so on.

After some research I accidentally stumbled across a solution that seemed too simple to be true, but so far it works. I wonder if people with more experience can take a look and tell me if I'm doing the right thing. And maybe other developers can benefit from the code too.

The idea is to inherit from `DefaultModelMetadataProvider` and override `CreatePropertyDetails` like this:

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DefaultModelMetadataProvider
{
    private readonly IMyContext _context;

    public CustomModelMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider, IMyContext context) : base(detailsProvider)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public CustomModelMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider, IOptions<MvcOptions> optionsAccessor, IMyContext context) : base(detailsProvider, optionsAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override DefaultMetadataDetails[] CreatePropertyDetails(ModelMetadataIdentity key)
    {
        // Call the base implementation
        var propsDetails = base.CreatePropertyDetails(key);

        // If the model type is our dynamic entity
        if (key.ModelType == typeof(JournalVoucher))
        {
            // Loop over the properties
            foreach (var propDetails in propsDetails)
            {
                // If the property is one of our dynamic properties
                string propertyName = propDetails.Key.Name;
                if (propertyName == nameof(JournalVoucher.Agent))
                {
                    // Set the display metadata passing a Func that dynamically 
                    // determines the display name by calling a custom service that
                    // we inject in the constructor, the service may call
                    // the database or rely on info from the HTTP Context
                    propDetails.DisplayMetadata = new DisplayMetadata
                    {
                        // Dynamic display name!!
                        DisplayName = () => _context.GetJournalVoucherPropertyDisplayName(propertyName)
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return propsDetails;
    }
}
```

Of course you must register this implementation in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyContext, MyContext>();
services.AddSingleton<IModelMetadataProvider, CustomModelMetadataProvider>();
```

Comment: Haven’t used this but looks very much like overriding serialisation so certainly feasible that it could be this simple!

Comment: [Related](http://www.michael-whelan.net/using-humanizer-with-asp-dotnet-core/)

Comment: Thanks Matt for sharing the HumanizerMetadataProvider implementation, it is indeed related, but after some investigation yesterday, turns out that whatever display names this implementation produces first time get cached by ASP.NET Core for the lifetime of the application, so it was not intended to produce dynamic results. Also you cannot inject services from the DI, so reaching any configuration in the database will not be trivial either

Comment: Well, for one you're registering this as a singleton, so of course nothing is going to change for the lifetime of the application. You need to make it request-scoped (if you can).

Comment: A singleton service can still return dynamic stuff, can it not? For example IHttpContextAccessor is a singleton but gives you access to the http context which is scoped. I didn't try to add the provider above as scoped tbh, I wonder if things will break since the default provider in MVC is registered as a singleton

Comment: @user1533706 The IHttpContextAccessor implementation is using commen reference with the Request to give access to the http context. So with every new request you get access to the new context. In your case the context will never be updated

Comment: @Kos perhaps the code would be clearer if we renamed IMyContext to IMyContextAccessor. So despite the fact that it is a singleton and will never be updated (like IHttpContextAccessor), it can still have a dynamic state which can change from request to request, (also like IHttpContextAccessor)